# Django m2m and saving objects

Tags: django, save, many-to-many

I have a couple of simple objects that have a many-to-many relationship. Django has joined them using obj1_obj2 table and it looks like this in mysql;

```
id  |  person_id  |  nationality_id  
-----------------------------------  
 1  |     1       |      1  
 2  |     1       |      2
```

Now when I save obj1 (which shows obj2 in as Multi-select in its form) the ids in the obj1_obj2 table increase even thow I have not changed them. For example I change a basic character field for obj1 on its form and save it and the the data in the joining table appears to be deleted and re-saved giving the entries new ids.

In fact I don't have to change anything all I have to do is save the form and the same thing happens.

All I am doing in the view is form.save(), nothing special. Is that the normal way that it works?

EDIT: Added Models, Views, Forms

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()  
    birthdate = models.CharField()  
    nationality = models.ManyToMany(Nationality)


class Employee(Person):
    employeeNum = models.CharField()


class FamilyMember(Person):  
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    relationship = models.CharField()


class Nationality(models.Model):
    abbrev = models.CharField()
    country = models.CharField()


class FamilyMemberDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FamilyMemeber
        exclude = ['employee']


def editFamilyMember(request, familyMember_id):
    familyMember = get_object_404(FamilMember, familyMember_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FamilyMemberDetailsForm(request.POST, instance=familyMember)
        if form.is_valid():  
          form.save()
    else:
        form = FamilyMemberDetailsForm(instance=familyMember) 


    return render_to_response(editForm.html, {'form':form},  
                              context_instance(RequestContext(request))
```

This is a cut down version of the models, but the same thing happens for saving an employee or familyMember. The FamilyMember I have shown because it is as simple as this I create the modelForm and then make changes and then save it. For the employee I do some more manipulation in the **init** of Form for the Nationality, mainly for presentation, and at first I thought it was this manipulation that was causing it, but as I said the same thing happens with the FamilyMember where I do nothing except save.

The Nationality is presented on the form as a multiselect box with a list and the user can select 1 or more from the list. If I just present the populated form and then save it without changing anything the id for the many-to-many table entry changes.

I have changed the example table titles also.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Does the obj1_obj2 table really have both id's set to 1 or is that just a typo?

Comment: Please show the code of your view.

Comment: I second the request for code... I don't think I get that effect on my m2m relations

Comment: The id's both being one was a typo.

Comment: I have add the code for the view, the models (cut down) and the modelform.

Comment: initial thoughts: you have `get_object_404` in your view, which I think should be `get_object_or_404`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the deletion of any existing rows in appname_obj1_obj2 is expected behavior when saving a form for an object that has a ManyToManyField.

You can see the clear() before the add(**values) in ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor and  ManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor in django/db/models/fields/related.py.

Pop open a shell and take a look at the queries yourself.  Something like this should show you the DELETE before the INSERT in the raw sql.

```
from django.db import connection
fm = FamilyMember.objects.get(pk=1)
form = FamilyMemberDetailsForm(instance=fm)
data = form.initial
data['name'] = "z%s" % data['name']  
form = FamilyMemberDetailsForm(data, instance=fm)
connection.queries = []  # clearing to limit the queries you have to look at
form.save()
for q in connection.queries:
    print("%s\n" % q['sql'])
```

Comment: So is there away to avoid this? Should I do a test before saving the form to see if the many-to-mamy has changed, is there a standard way that this is done or is it just not looked at as a problem?

Comment: It is possible to manage the entities in the junction table yourself but ask yourself if it is worth the effort before starting on this path.  This table is small and no doubt fully indexed, so operations on it should be very fast.  If you call save(commit=False), save_m2m() will become available on the form object (instead of being called inside the save()).  You can then try your hand with person.nationality.add() and .remove() for your own m2m relationship management instead of calling form.save_m2m().  Again, make sure this is something worth spending time on before you ditch save_m2m().

Comment: Your point about the time spent versus worth is taken. I think I will just leave it alone. Thanks you for your help.